# Running perf to do the test - cache miss 100%

Tags: linux, performance, caching, cpu-cache, perf

I am trying to execute perf on my host.

OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Perf command:

```
perf stat -B -e cache-references,cache-misses,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations sleep 5
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':
```

Result: Cache miss 100%

CPU: Intel Xeon Processor D-1520

I not yet figure out why the cache miss can reach 100% but I suspect this issue might be related to CPU. Any idea?

---

workload
[image]

perf message
[image]

---

I am not sure if cachegrind does the similar cache profiling as perf. In cachegrind, things work and there is no big difference on my platform compared to others.

cachegrind message

[image]

CPU Info

[image]

Comment: What is the workload? Did you check the system is not running a greedy task?

Comment: Could you show actual output of `perf`? Could you run it under root?

Comment: @amigadev it's a newly installed system so I guess it has no greedy task running when I did the test.

Comment: Strange, do you run virtual machines or containers there?

Comment: @avd nope I don't run vm or container on my host

Comment: Then I would suggest you filing a bug for perf, because your stat is close to impossible.

Comment: @avd if this is a bug in perf, I would try other cache profiling tools. Any suggestions?

Comment: @amigadev post updated. Any idea?

Comment: what exactly do you expect your CPU to do while sleeping? Can you try doing `ls`?

Comment: @Leeor I execute a simple program instead of sleeping. The output is the same. Any idea?

Comment: @Sam Sorry but there is no reason to get zero cache miss. Maybe your processor is specific by one detail that makes the difference (that would make it not recognized by perf). Maybe it is supported in a recent version of perf.

Comment: By the way, cachegrind doesn't profile the real HW, it only simulates how its cache would have behaved, so it won't reproduce any problem with HW counters (or mismatches in perf version)

Comment: @amigadev I agree with you. I am not sure how perf recognizes these processors. Is there any check list available online? I also tried to download the latest version of perf but got the same result.

Comment: @Leeor You are right. On the other hand, does perf profiles the real HW ? If so, as amigadev, is there any list of processor online that perf can recognize ?

Comment: You can try using direct event IDs, I think you have a Broadwell, so try this list - http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/intel-broadwell-events.php

Comment: @Sam @Leeor AFAIK there is no list, you have to look at Linux sources in `arch/x86/kernel/cpu`. There is the file `perf_event_intel.c` with a switch/case for specific CPU models (as given by `/proc/cpuinfo`).

Comment: @Sam In case of suspicious behaviour with perf, it is often necessary to look at sources. Another example is about the identity of LLC (if it is L2 or L3 cache) or I remember on another architecture L1-dcache-store-misses was zero because it was not able to distinguish load and store misses, even if the event was listed. That's too complicated to manage all that.

Comment: @Leeor yea, I think it's Broadwell. I will have a try with your link.

Comment: @amigadev I just checked the perf_event_intel.c and in the line number 3480 in my downloaded kernel source. There is a switch case pointed to 14nm Broadwell Xeon D.

Comment: @amigadev so I think in this case, should it suppose to work ?

Comment: @Sam I think you are in the unfortunate situation with a kernel version that was at the time of the rewriting of this file `perf_event_intel.c` because I see it has vastly changed between 3.19 and 4.0, AFAIK. That's strange you are in 3.19.0 and have the new file... So I'm quite disconcerted.

Comment: @amigadev I am not sure if you are familiar with Oprofile as Leeor suggested. Does Oprofile can help me check the health of my cpu cache ? thanks for your reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91570/discussion-between-sam-and-amigadev).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my test on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit machine Intel i7-3770 CPU. Test seems to be ok.

```
perf stat -B -e cache-references,cache-misses,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations sleep 5`

 Performance counter stats for sleep 5:

            15,375      cache-references
             1,790      cache-misses              #   11.642 % of all cache refs
           897,607      cycles
           684,540      instructions              #    0.76  insns per cycle
           139,092      branches
                58      faults
                 0      migrations

       5.001000990 seconds time elapsed
```

Linux Kernel version on my PC:

```
$ uname -a
Linux plex 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Installed software to install perf:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-3.19.0-26-generic

$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1601.851
CPU max MHz:           3900.0000
CPU min MHz:           1600.0000
BogoMIPS:              6784.60
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Comment: Things dont change even though I upgraded to 15.04.

Comment: @Sam Maybe it is not enough and your kernel is from end of 2014. What is the model of your CPU in `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: @amigadev kernel version: 3.19.0-30-generic